# HTML5 Homepage based on menu clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a very simple sports website where the homepage has links to different sports like football , basketball , netball etc . what I want is when a user clicks on football , the value to be stored so as next time the visitor gets to the page it will open the football page.

so far I have try using html5 localstorage , but i can't see it working.

```
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store

    localStorage.setItem("homepage", "index");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("homepage");
} else {
    //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}

function homepage_football(){
  localStorage.setItem("homepage", "football");
}
```

HTML - Homepage

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url()."/sport/football/"?>" onclick="homepage_football()">
 <a href="<?php echo site_url()."/sport/basketball/"?>" onclick="homepage_basketball()">
 <a href="<?php echo site_url()."/sport/netball/"?>" onclick="homepage_netball()">
```

Comment: How are you redirecting the user?

Comment: Show HTML that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like the following:

```
setHomepage(page) {
  localStorage.setItem('homepage', page)
}

redirectHomepage() {
  let page = localStorage.getItem('homepage')
  page && (window.location.href = page)
}

// on open of `football` page
setHomepage('football')

// on index load
redirectHomepage()
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution . I have updated the HTML part of my question , i want when a user clicks a link on the homepage then a localstorage should be set for the homepage . And also a user can change the the homepage . Do i need multiple function for each link as i did ? how do i update the local storage item ? please help

Comment: i have tried your solution but it returns undefined in the url . can u please check my updated question and advise accordingly . thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
</script>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```